# Disable the hiding of title tooltip text when clicked?

Tags: html, css

If I set a title attribute to an image then a tooltip appears when you hover over it. If you click (while hovering) it disappears. Is there a way to stop it disappearing when you click?

Comment: I don't think you can - it is default browser behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a no javascript solution so I used this:
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score -1):

Don't know how to do that by HTML/CSS, but you can use Javascript instead?

Here an explaination:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Hope this helps you.